# метод, возвращающий ответ на вопрос: правда ли, что a + b = c?

Tags: методы

как реализовать метод, возвращающий ответ на вопрос: правда ли, что a + b = c?
Допустимая погрешность – 0.0001 (1E-4)

Answer (score 1):

Вот на Си:

```
return fabs(a+b-c) < 1e-4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так короче:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(eq(1, 1, 2.00005, 0.0001));
    }

    static boolean eq(double a, double b, double c, double eps) {
        return Math.abs(a + b - c) < eps;
    }
}
```